# Grails war shows errors while deploying in tomcat

Tags: grails

My grails war is running fine when i run it with grails run-war  on my local machine but i gives me following error when i upload on my ubuntu server 
one important thing here i want to mention is ( i already uploaded the same war file earlier day it was working and when i undeploy it  and deploy it it showing me the errors)
i even tested the same war file in some other windows system it working fine

```
Feb 18, 2012 11:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transactional resources]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 18, 2012 11:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.MyThreadLocal] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$MyThreadLocal@80fb85]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 18, 2012 11:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transaction synchronizations]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 18, 2012 11:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Prototype beans currently in creation]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 18, 2012 11:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2@ef96]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
```

Comment: And, does it work after this warnings? Actually it's about just *undeployed* application, not *deployed*

Comment: @splix the project is not running could you help us

Comment: Do you have any other errors? Maybe `PermGem space` error? Did you tried to restart Tomcat?

Comment: Not really an answer, but we faced similar problems. Turned out a xml file with the JNDI database config was not included in the WAR and somehow got deleted from /etc/tomcat6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Tomcat's logs directory. You're just seeing what's written to stdout, but there's probably useful information in another log file, e.g. localhost.2012-02-18.log or catalina.2012-02-18.log. There might also be information in stacktrace.log

Comment: i have checked all the log files but i couldnt find any other errors  any help please

Comment: i found some error like this Cannot create directory: /usr/share/tomcat6/.grails/projects/redkanproject/searchable-index/production/index/gallery

Comment: You can specify the location of the Searchable plugin's Lucene index to point to a writeable directory with the `compassConnection` attribute in `myproject/grails-app/conf/Searchable.groovy` - see https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-searchable/trunk/src/conf/Searchable.groovy for the template which has comments describing usage. Run `grails install-searchable-config` to create the file if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the temp, and work directory of tomcat . And restart the tomcat

Comment: i restarted it more than 6 times  and also i cleared all temp and webapps files from my tomcats working directory